# Incorrect value on networkx betweenness centrality

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm analyzing some data using networkx by extracting a few characteristics of a graph created from this data. But first, I wanted to understand all of the steps on the calculation of those characteristics, to check the values correctness.
One of the characteristics I need is the betweenness centrality of a weighted undirected graph, so I'm trying to calculate it by hand, on a small graph made by this edge list:

```
0 1 1
0 2 1
1 2 5
3 1 5
```

Where the first number is the source, the second is the target and the third is the weight of the connection. Calling the function `nx.betweenness_centrality` on this graph the results, without normalization are:  `{'0': 2.0, '1': 2.0, '2': 0.0, '3': 0.0}`, but it doesn't makes sense to me because using the formula given by [networkx documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality) this would mean that the number of shortest paths in the graph is half of the number of shortest paths that passes through nodes 0 and 1. Is this a problem on my interpretation, or some error on the actual code? If someone could help me calculating those values on this small graph, or any other weighted graph i would appreciate as well.

Edit: if the exact function call is needed, the code was:

```
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist("dummy")
nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight="weight", normalized=False)
```

Where dummy is a file containing exactly the weights as described above.